# Flutter: Texts in container are centered instead of left-aligned

Tags: flutter, containers, text-alignment

I would like to display some rows of text in a Container. The texts are written as AutoSizedText so that they can be longer than one row. All texts should be left-aligned, so I use *textAlign: TextAlign.left*. But if in the container there are more than one AutoSizedText, the texts are displayed centered instead of left-aligned.

Does anybody know what my mistake is?

```
new Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            margin: const EdgeInsets.all(30.0),
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 3),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),),
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                AutoSizeText("Title", textAlign: TextAlign.left, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, 
                   maxLines: 20,),
                AutoSizeText("Date: 01.01.2000", textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 20,),
                AutoSizeText("Author: John Doe", textAlign: TextAlign.left, 
                   overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 20,),
                AutoSizeText("This is the message which should be displayed.",
                   textAlign: TextAlign.left, overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis, maxLines: 20,),
            ]))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because of `crossAxisAlignment` property of [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html), which is **Center** by default

> read this in [offcial docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Flex/crossAxisAlignment.html)

To fix this write below code inside `Column`,

```
Column(
crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.start
...
)
```

Find your complete [solution here gist](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/aae804a18cba801b3d812e1698d86b37)

output:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, the text is still left aligned. Maybe it's because the child of Colum is Container and not the AutoSizedText itself. But I still don't know how to solve my problem...

Comment: try to add `alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,` inside container.

Comment: When I insert this, the text which is written in the last AutoSizetext is moved to the left so that it is left-justified. All other texts still have the same offset to the bottom text as in the picture above. So the whole text is shifted left, but only the last part is left-justified.

Comment: I tried to run your code myself, it works perfectly fine with `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,`

Comment: I have created a [gist](https://gist.github.com/raviganwal/aae804a18cba801b3d812e1698d86b37) for you.

Comment: Yes, the mistake was mine. Excuse me and thank you very much for your effort.

Comment: You don't have to thank me :), Just accept the answer.